# Default in switch case is executed in all cases

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my angular app, I use this switch case to see if a file is being uploaded send progress, along with a message, as a default case ( when the file is not being uploaded ) I want to send another message, which I tried in the code below, only thing is the default case gets executed every time ( both cases file being uploaded and not being uploaded )
How do i fix this ?

```
this.dragdropService
      .addFiles(this.form.value.txt, this.datasource._id)
      .subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        switch (event.type) {
          case HttpEventType.Sent:
            console.log('Request has been made!');
            break;
          case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
            console.log('Response header has been received!');
            break;
          case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
            this.progress = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
            console.log(`Uploaded! ${this.progress}%`);
            break;
          case HttpEventType.Response:
            console.log('File uploaded successfully!', event.body);
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.progress = 0;
              this.fileArr = [];
              this.fileObj = [];
              this.msg = 'File uploaded successfully!';
            }, 3000);
           break;
          default:
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.msg = 'Error: CSV Or Text Files Only!';
            }, 4000);
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Usually each `case` should have its `break` ;)

Comment: You have forgotten about `break` in last `case`.

Comment: Other than the missing `break` is it working? I was wondering if `HTTPEvent<any>` should be  `HttpResponse<any>` per https://angular.io/guide/http#handling-interceptor-events

Comment: No, I only forgot to add the break in the code i added, but it's not working with the break too